# How to install AMD gpu drivers in non-LTS version

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, radeon

I'm using **Ubuntu 22.10** kinetic version and a brand new **AMD Radeon RX 6600**.

When I installed Ubuntu 22.10 I saw that all the drivers offered by this distro were open, causing it to underperform the NVIDIA 1050Ti mobile on my laptop, when it shouldn't (here you can see a comparison between the two: https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/compare/3922vs4465/GeForce-GTX-1050-Ti-with-Max-Q-Design-vs-Radeon-RX-6600).

Using the open drivers I'm getting a very poor performance, about 33% of what I expected. My new graphics card is supposed to be about 3X more powerful than my laptop one. For example: the performance obtained in `glmark2` is about 9,000 points for the NVIDIA vs. 8,000 points for the AMD.

On AMD's proprietary driver website, they only offer drivers for Ubuntu versions 20.04 and 22.04, i.e. exclusively LTS. These are the ones that would offer the full performance of the graphics card.

Is there any way to get the proprietary drivers using non-LTS versions of Ubuntu?

Comment: You don't need drovers for AMD. They are included in the kernel.

Comment: @Pilot6, yes, but they are OPEN drivers and its performance is poor. Maybe they performance is 33% of what I expected

Comment: Actually the drivers from AMD site don't really improve performance. It is unlike Nvidia.

Comment: My new graphics card is supposed to be about 3 times more powerful than my laptop. Well, the performance obtained in glmark2 is about 9,000 points for the NVIDIA and 8,000 for the AMD.

Comment: You already posted this question before: [How to install AMD propietary drivers in Ubuntu 22.10 kinetic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1453873/how-to-install-amd-propietary-drivers-in-ubuntu-22-10-kinetic), it's a valid question though.

Comment: Probably this will help in finding a solution.
https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/o8ps39/how_to_install_proprietary_amd_gpu_drivers_on_a/